# How to show progress dialog when I click on a button using AsyncTask in a class that yet extends MapActivity

Tags: android, inheritance, android-asynctask

I have a program that search some elements and show these on a GoogleMap.
I want to show a progress dialog before the end of all procedures that set the various geopoint on the map.

Searching I have found this code to show the progress dialog before the end of a method.

```
    ProgressDialog dialog; 
private class Test extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 

    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this); 
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...."); 
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true); 
        dialog.setCancelable(true); 
        dialog.show(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) { 
        try { 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                public void run() { 

                } 
            }); 
            //your code 

    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Void params) { 
        dialog.dismiss(); 
        //result 

    } 
}
```

The class where I must add the async task is something like this:

```
public class FindItOnMap extends MapActivity{
static String[] foundResults;

@Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.ricerca_condominio);
         mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);

         mapController = mapView.getController();

         mapView.setClickable(true);

         mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

         mapController.setZoom(12);

         myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
         List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
         overlays.add(myLocationOverlay);
         myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
                 ...........



         ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btSearch)).setOnClickListener(mSearchListenerListener);


}


        OnClickListener mSearchListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    String Location=editorLocation.getText().toString();
                    String name=editorName.getText().toString();
                //static method that updates the lists foundResult
                search(name, location);
                //static method that use the static array foundResult to update the map
                updateMapWithResult();

            }
     };
```

The methods that requires time before return the solution are invoked when I click on a button

```
search(name, location);

updateMapWithResult();
```

The problem is that my class extends yet MapActivity and I cannot use multiple inheritance to extend another class. 
How could I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you calling any function of this Class from any other class??

Comment: no. I have a Class that show a GUI with a Map and a search function that update a map, and want to integrate an AsyncTask of this form before the creation of the content of the GUI

Comment: Please check the Way that i have posted below.

Comment: I have tried to use your suggestion with no success, now I have updated the question adding more code and detail.

Comment: Please Check My Edited Answer and feel free to ask if you don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use multiple inheritance, you can define your `AsyncTask` as an inner class and use an instantiated object of the `AsycTask` you defined to do your job. Something like this:

```
public class FindItOnMap extends MapActivity {

static String[] foundResults;
private ProgressDialog dialog;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.ricerca_condominio);
     mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);

     mapController = mapView.getController();

     mapView.setClickable(true);

     mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

     mapController.setZoom(12);

     myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
     List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
     overlays.add(myLocationOverlay);
     myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
             ...........



     ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btSearch)).setOnClickListener(mSearchListenerListener);


     }

    OnClickListener mSearchListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                String Location=editorLocation.getText().toString();
                String name=editorName.getText().toString();
             //Call the AsyncTask here
            new YourCustomAsyncTask().execute(new String[] {name, location});

        }


    private class YourCustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void> { 

        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
           dialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this); 
           dialog.setMessage("Loading...."); 
           dialog.setIndeterminate(true); 
           dialog.setCancelable(true); 
           dialog.show(); //Maybe you should call it in ruinOnUIThread in doInBackGround as suggested from a previous answer
        } 

        @Override 
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) { 
           try { 

              search(strings[0], string[1]);

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                 public void run() { 
                    updateMapWithResult(); //Or call it onPostExecute before progressDialog's dismiss. I believe this method updates the UI so it should run on UI thread
                 } 
               }); 

           } catch(Exception e) {
           }

        }

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Void params) { 
        dialog.dismiss(); 
        //result 

    } 


.....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot use this solution to show the progress windows when I click... I have updated the question and added more code and details for clarification.

Comment: @Asgard I updated my answer. I think that is what you need. Hope that it helps:)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I get an illegal state exception: System services not available to activities before `onCreate()`

Comment: This exception occurs when you try to use your Activity's context before it is initiated or you pass a wrong context. Can you provide the code you tried and the exception's stack trace?

Comment: I have fixed this problem (was not relatet to your solution) however with your suggestion the waiting windows works but doesn't updates the map(maybe is needed a non-null return statement in doInBackground... I don't know), if I try to move the upate map method in onPostExecute, the static arrays `foundResults` results empty and get a NullPointer Exception. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hmm, maybe the problem is that you have not initialized the foundResults static variable. In onPostExecute, it throws a NullPointerException because it is not in a try catch block as is in doInBackground. In other words, maybe the NullPointerException is also being thrown in doInBackground but is being caught in the try catch block and that's why your map is not updated and you do not get informed about the exception.

Comment: No, the problem is another the method 
`search(strings[0], string[1]);` doesn't update the static list 
`foundResults` of the class where is located this inner class, the list, results filled with null value... How could I solve this? nb The list `foundResults` is a list of custom Location objects

Comment: @Asgard Do you really need the `foundResults` variable to be declared as `static`? Maybe that's what is causing you problems, i am not sure. Try debugging the `search(strings[0], string[1]);`. Also, can you post the code of that method?

Comment: Unfortunately I need the list static

you can see the most of the class code at this link

[link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/32771602/FindItOnMap.java)

(I have deleted some unrelated parts)

Comment: In the `searchPlaces` method, check if your JSONArray is not empty and does not throws an `JSONException` when you access it. Since you said that `foundResults` has `null` values in it, maybe you are trying to access a JSON value using a JSON key that does not exists causing a `JSONException`  that is being caught by `catch (Throwable t)`, leaving your `foundResults` array with null values.

Comment: Json works properly and If I use the methods outside inner Async class  the map is updated correctly(the actual version of my software works but I need to use a waiting dialog because if the connection is slow the retrieve of date requires a while... so is necessary a waiting windows to show that the works is in progress otherwise the app could seems blocked)

Comment: I am starting to deplete of ideas, sorry:S A last suggestion would be to create a local variable such as `String[] foundResults_local` inside your `CustomAsyncTask` and update that variable in your `searchPlaces` method instead of `foundResults`. Then, `onPostExcecute` set `foundResults = foundResults_local`. I am not sure if this do the trick though.

Comment: This damn problem drive me mad, I cannot find a valid way to get a working waiting dialag...however Thanks for the help

Comment: If in the outer class all fields are correctly updated you could run `search()` in a thread in the outer class with a `boolean completed` and in another parallel thread the waiting task that simply show the waiting dialog until `completed==true` and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

So algorithm shouldn't be tricky.

So implement your `AsyncTask` *Class* as *inner class* of your *Activity Main Class*. Then i recommend to you call `show()` method before you executing `Task` so:

```
progressDialog.show();
Test test = new Test();
test.execute();
```

**Note:** You shouldn't call `show()` method in `onPreExecute` method of `AsyncTask`

Then in your `onPostExecute` method just call `dismiss()` for *dismissing* `ProgressDialog`

```
@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Void params) { 
   progressDialog.dismiss(); 
}
```

And now it should works.

---

This

```
@Override 
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) { 
        try { 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                public void run() { 

                } 
            }); 
            //your code 

    }
```

never do it again! `doInBackground` method is method that is *designed* for **long tasks on background thread** and in this method you shouldn't, you can't, you musn't update your `UI`!

For updating your `UI` `AsyncTask` offers methods as `onProgressUpdate` and `onPostExecute` and you should respect it.

Comment: I believe you can call the method show() of the progressDialog in the onPreExecute method of the Async Task since the onPreExecute is running on the UI thread.

Comment: Angelo, i solved a few topics when men had problems with similar problem. onPreExecute method is not right place for updating UI, there is still many problems although docs say opposite.

Comment: I did not know that. Every time i use AsyncTask with a progressDialog showing in onPreExecute everything works fine. Anyways, thanks for the information, i will search a bit more of what you said:)

Comment: yes, there is strange behaviour, for someone it works, for someone not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot use this solution to show the progress windows when I click... I have updated the question and added more code and details for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class FindItOnMap extends MapActivity{
static String[] foundResults;
 String Location;
 String name;
@Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.ricerca_condominio);
         mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
         mapController = mapView.getController();
         mapView.setClickable(true);
         mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
         mapController.setZoom(12);
         myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
         List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
         overlays.add(myLocationOverlay);
         myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
                 ...........



        ((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btSearch))  
                      .setOnClickListener(mSearchListenerListener);

        OnClickListener mSearchListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) 
         {
              Location=editorLocation.getText().toString();
              name=editorName.getText().toString();

    /*===You Just Go On to Call search(name,location) in the doInBackground part  
 and updateMapWithResult(); in the postExecute() part so that   
only after gettting the result from the search method,the updateMapWithResult();   
will be called in the Async Task like this...==*/

              new Test().execute();

        }
     };
}

    private class Test extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 
    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    { 
       dialog=ProgressDialog.show(YourClassContext,"Loading","",false);

    } 

    @Override 
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
    { 
    try 
    { 

      search(name, location);

    } 
    }); 


    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Void params) 
    { 
       updateMapWithResult();
       dialog.dismiss(); 
    //result 

    } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot use this solution to show the progress windows when I click... I have updated the question and added more code and details for clarification.